# What is this Substance in my Induction Cooker?

Tags: repair, oven

On my mobile induction cooker (GIC 3035, [User Manual](https://www.manualslib.de/manual/764656/Metro-Gic3035.html)), one of the rubber feet came loose and subsequently fell off. The feet were fastened by nuts on the inside, so I opened up the housing without thinking too hard about it.

As can be seen in the pictures, there is a white substance between the iron core (?) and the cooktop side.

[image: Coils side]
[image: Cooktop side]

Is this simply thermal paste? Will I get anyone killed or start a fire if I try to fix this myself?

I could not find a disassembly guide or other technical documentation detailing what this is.

(I hope this is *only just* on topic; I have not found a better StackExchange site to ask this.)

Comment: Yes, it's thermal compound (heat sink grease) and should not be a big deal. Of course the manual proudly displaying (a very large) CE mark and no NRTL mark is something of a concern for safety, or lack thereof; one that probably goes with a quality of construction where the feet fall off.

Comment: Is there a UL or ETL mark on the device itself, or a Nationally Recognized Testing Laboratory mark from whatever place in the world you live? If not then the device is not tested to not be hazardous and might kill someone or start a fire with or without you working on it. I mean, really, the foot fell off...that's not quality construction/assembly.

Comment: that's so the thermistor can read the temp from the bottom of the pan quicker.

Comment: @Ecnerwal To be fair, it worked well for 10 years while in regular use, and this is the first issue I had with the device. It has a TÜV certificate on the bottom, so it should be tested safe to use.

Comment: Both of you did answer my main question, so I'd be happy to accept if either of you wrote an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That appears to be thermal paste. It bridges the sensor to the glass plate so it can more accurately measure the pan temperature when the device is in temperature mode. If it's all dried out you can either replace it with non-conductive thermal paste, or just leave it be.